# Multiple Where statements in MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a SQL statement where I want the WHERE part to be dynamically filled by the calling function. The function that calls the statement should be able to pass one or more parameters with 'OR'. Unfortunately, the statement always takes only the first entry.

```
$category = 'cat1' OR 'cat2' OR 'cat3';
$result = getEntries($category, $mysqli);

function getEntries($category, $mysqli){
    $queryData = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = ?"); 
    $queryData->bind_param("s", $category);
    $queryData->execute();
    $queryData = $queryData->get_result();
    return $queryData; 
}
```

I only get results for "cat1"
Thanks for your help

Comment: No, I see the result for 'cat1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **OR** operator to assign a variable, which will assign one value at a time, if you want the number of categories dynamically then you can modify your code like below:

```
$categories = ['cat1','cat2','cat3'];
$result = getEntries($categories, $mysqli);

function getEntries($categories, $mysqli){
   $plcs = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($categories)-1, "?");

   $queryData = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category IN ({$plcs})"); 
   $queryData->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($categories)), ...$categories);
   $queryData->execute();
   return $queryData->get_result();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong assignment .

```
$category = 'cat1' OR 'cat2' OR 'cat3';
```

correct it . See the basics of bind param from below :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

And multiple where statment can be like this :

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE category in ("cat1","cat2","cat3")
```

also you can use following when your database has extra space or want to match anything containing cat1,cat2,cat3:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE category like '%cat1%' or category like '%cat2%' or
category like '%cat3%'
```

Comment: As I don´t know how many categories the user will select, this is not an suitable solutions

Comment: you have to append all the category to $category variable. @Beji